# How to overcome jar dependency hell when multiple modules use the same jar?

Tags: java, android, build, jar, intellij-idea

I've got an Android project that has multiple modules. These are all Git submodules, and several of them are packaged with the same jars (android support v4, Guice, Roboguice, etc.). My main project also has these same dependencies, so I've got three copies of these jars, one in my project, and one in each of two submodules.

When I build, it fails at the dex stage, complaining that certain classes have already been added. I can hack around this, by getting rid of the jars from all the modules, except one, then pointing the dependencies to that location, but it just feels so dirty. There's got to be a better way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a build tool like Maven or Ivy that manages dependencies for you, so you don't have to check JARs into your project.

Comment: Not sure why someone dv'ed this.  The question screams the answer, "Maven."

Comment: @djechlin Probably the downy guy screamed too because he throught and read about Maven?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Eclipse ADT? If so this problem has been solved with the latest ADT. The old one used to have the problem you are describing but the new one should work.
Check this link out for details:
http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

Comment: Sorry then, I don't think IntelliJ supports that in the current version. Your best bet is to use external build tool(like Maven) as Matt has suggested

Comment: I've been using Ant as my external build tool. Is this an inherent problem with using an Ant setup?

Comment: I don't believe Ant supports that right now. One thing you can try is to create a new library project that has the jars, and reference it from the other projects.