# Getting error retrieving data from column family using cassandra-jdbc dreiver

Tags: java, database, cassandra

when i am retrieving data from column family using Cssandra-JDBC driver. i got error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_cql3_query(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Lorg/apache/cassandra/thrift/Compression;Lorg/apache/cassandra/thrift/ConsistencyLevel;)Lorg/apache/cassandra/thrift/CqlResult;

at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.execute(CassandraConnection.java:447)
at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.execute(CassandraConnection.java:472)
at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.doExecute(CassandraStatement.java:161)
at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.executeQuery(CassandraStatement.java:226)
at CassandraJDBCTest.main(CassandraJDBCTest.java:19)
```

Code is

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws SQLException{

    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/TestExample");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Name,Age FROM Users WHERE keyname='001';");

     rs.next();


        System.out.println(rs.getString("Name"));


       System.out.println(rs.getInt(2));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missing dependencies: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.**NoSuchMethodError**

I have a feeling that the classpath is just not configured correctly (why the L's?):

```
Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
Lorg/apache/cassandra/thrift/Compression;
Lorg/apache/cassandra/thrift/ConsistencyLevel;
...
```

If you want to save yourself of [dependency hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666637/how-to-overcome-jar-dependency-hell-when-multiple-modules-use-the-same-jar) try using maven, the Datastax java driver has a [maven central repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-parent/1.0.2) and you just need to include the dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
   <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT**
Sorry, didnt realise you are using JDBC. The cassandra jdbc driver has also [got a maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache-extras.cassandra-jdbc/cassandra-jdbc/1.2.5):

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache-extras.cassandra-jdbc</groupId>
<artifactId>cassandra-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How i can set class path,same as java or its different.

Comment: i got the solution.i have added "apache-cassandra-1.2.8.jar",and i am able to execute the program.